# How to find out if array has Zero and how to delete it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array 
IDs

```
[671322109, 671322111, 0, 671322113]
```

How to findout if IDs includes 0 and how to delete it

```
if (IDs.includes(0)) {

  IDs.filter(Number);
```

and

```
IDs.splice(0);
   }
```

Not Working

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: `Array.filter(Boolean);`

Comment: if (IDs.includes(0)) {

                IDs.filter(Number);
            }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @AhmedHalim `filter` doesn't modify original array, you have to assign returned value

Comment: change `IDs.filter(Number)` to `IDs = IDs.filter(Boolean);`

Comment: Thank you @Durga - Nick

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do it this way.

```
let ids = [671322109, 671322111, 0, 671322113];
ids = ids.filter(id => id != 0);
```